# Using Rx to subscribe to progress event and still get result on completion

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have to call a method belonging to an external component. The signature of the method looks something like this:

```
IImportedData Import(string fileName, Action<int> progress);
```

This operation can take a long time to execute, so I need to call it asynchronously and report progress to the user. I'm looking at different approaches to calling it (Rx, TPL, ThreadPool) to find something expressive and clear, however I'm struggling to come up with a way to do it in Rx.

At first glance, the idea of reporting progress using Rx seems like a perfect fit - it's a stream of incoming ints relating to progress. The only catch is that when the operation completes, I need to inspect `IImportedData` to display a result to the user. OnCompleted isn't intended for that purpose, which leads me down a path of having a class that exposes two IObservable streams, and then a method to "Start" the operation.

```
private class Importer : IObservable<int>, IObservable<IImportedData>
```

Feels clunky and I'm sure there's a better way that I don't know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things come to mind up front:

1. `Task<T>` and `IProgress<T>` seem like a better fit for this task
2. Implementing `IObservable<T>` is generally frowned upon. Creating composite instances using static methods on `Observable` is the recommended approach.

If you stick with Rx, I'd recommend having a look at [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abe175c9-fad6-4d9c-b3e1-012a14f96fda/exposing-progress-vs-data) I had with the Rx guys a few years back. Jeffrey van Gogh ended up recommending an `Either<TLeft, TRight>` response that you would automatically route callbacks depending on whether the message was a "progress" event or a "result" event. If I was in that position again, that's certainly the direction I would take.

Comment: `Either<Left, Right>` seems obvious now that you mention it. i'll give that a crack. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah. ``Either<Left,Right>`` is the way I would go. I use a similar pattern for passing errors through Rx. ``IObservable<Exceptional<T>>`` either passes an ``Exception`` or a ``T``. This is just a special case of ``Either`` and the pattern has saved my bacon on many occasions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Func<string, Action<int>, IObservable<IImportedData>> create =
    (fileName, progress) =>
        Observable.Create<IImportedData>(o =>
        {
            var foo = new Foo();
            var subject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);

            var d1 = subject.Subscribe(progress);

            var result = foo.Import(fileName, n => subject.OnNext(n));

            var d2 = subject
                .Where(x => x == 100)
                .Select(x => result)
                .Subscribe(o);

            return new CompositeDisposable(d1, d2);
        });
```

I haven't tested it, but something like this should give you a relatively clean Rx way of doing what you're after. You may need to add in your synchonization context.